# readdir(): re-reading certain files

Tags: c++, readdir, dirent.h

I got a function which task is to rename all files in a folder however, it re-rename certain files:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtMER.png, the same kind of "error" keeps occurring for every tenth number onwards. What exactly is causing this "error"?

The two arguments to the function is the path for the folder and what start value the first file should have.

```c
int lookup(std::string path, int *start){
        int number_of_chars;
        std::string old_s, file_format, new_s;
        std::stringstream out;
        DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *ent;

        dir = opendir (path.c_str());
        if (dir != NULL) {
            // Read pass "." and ".."
            ent = readdir(dir);
            ent = readdir(dir);
            // Change name of all the files in the folder
            while((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL){
                // Old string value
                old_s = path;
                old_s.append(ent->d_name);
                // Get the format of the image
                file_format = ent->d_name;
                number_of_chars = file_format.rfind(".");
                file_format.erase(0,number_of_chars);
                // New string value
                new_s = path;
                out << *start;
                new_s += out.str();
                new_s.append(file_format);
                std::cout << "Successfully changed name on " << ent->d_name << "\tto:\t" << *start << file_format << std::endl;
                // Switch name on the file from old string to new string
                rename(old_s.c_str(), new_s.c_str());

                out.str("");
                *start = *start+1;
            }
            closedir (dir);
        }
        // Couldn't open
        else{
            std::cerr << "\nCouldn't open folder, check admin privileges and/or provided file path\n" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're enumerating the very thing you're changing; the directory content. Create a `std::set<>` of filename you've already changed (the new names) and skip anything in the set. Either that or read the *entire* directory *first*, loading all filenames into a `std::list<>` or some other such appropriate container, then iterate that list, renaming along the way.

Comment: SideNote: if there is a guarantee the *first* to files are always "." and "..", I'm not aware of it. you needs to test for those *explicitly* unless I'm incorrect (which would not be the first time).

Comment: Okay, had a feeling it was something like that but figured that once I called openedir that it ignored what I did in the folder afterwards. And the few times I have used dirent(windows only) it always seemed to have those two parents folders, will change it so it test instead of just reading pass them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are renaming files to the same folder in which the original files were, resulting in an infinite loop. You renamed `04.png` to `4.png` but since you are iterating over all files in the folder, at some point you're going to iterate to the "new" `4.png` file (in your smaple, on the 40th iteration) and rename that file to `40.png` and so on...

The easiest way to resolve this with **minimal changes** to the existing code is to "rename" (move) the files to a temporary folder with their new names. Something like:

```
new_s = temp_path;
out << *start;
new_s += out.str();
new_s.append(file_format);
// Switch name on the file from old string to new string
rename(old_s.c_str(), new_s.c_str());
```

and when you are done renaming all the files in `path` (outside the `while` loop), delete the folder and "rename" (move) `temp_path` to `path:

```
closedir (dir);
deletedir(path);
rename(temp_path, path);
```

`

Comment: Ah, okay, was afraid that it was such an issue. I'm guessing it can be solved by saving all of the files in a vector/array first, close dir, and then rename the files?

Comment: @DavidS that is certainly how I would approach it. Less chance of global annihilation or mistakes.

Comment: That would be the better solution. My solution focused on minimal code changes

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems I see:

- Renaming files causes them to be fed to your algorithm twice.
- Your algorithm for computing the new filename is wrong.

You should be able to write a test for this easily, which in turn should help you fix the problem or write a more specific question. Other than that, I don't see any grave issues, but it would help if you reduced the scope of variables a bit, which would make sure that different iterations don't influence each other.